# Polymorphism and passing

Tags: c++, game-development

I am writing a text based RPG, and I have three classes that inherit from a super class, they all have special attacks that they can perform, at the same time I have a class that holds the function which handles battles in my game.

Now how do I get the unique special abilities functions for whatever role the player chooses into the battle function?

Also I am using the vector.push_back method to handle how my sub classes are referenced.

Comment: Have you seen circlemud.org?

Answer (score 2):

You just need a virtual member function in your superclass:

```
class Superclass
{
    virtual void specialAbility() = 0;
};
```

And implementations in your subclasses:

```
class Subclass1 : public Superclass
{
    void specialAbility()
    {
        // Do something specific to this subclass...
    }
};

class Subclass2 : public Superclass
{
    void specialAbility()
    {
        // Do something specific to this subclass...
    }
};
```

Now when you do your battles, you could do something like this (**edited to put in class**):

```
class BattleDoer
{
    void doBattle(std::vector<Superclass*> combatants)
    {
        for (unsigned int index = 0; index < combatants.size(); index++)
        {
            combatants.at(index)->specialAbility();
        }
    }
};
```

This will cause the appropriate member function defined in the subclass to be called on each of the combatant objects.

**Edit:**

To populate your combatant list and call the `doBattle()` function, you can do something like this:

```
int main()
{
    Superclass* combatant1 = new Subclass1;
    Superclass* combatant2 = new Subclass2;

    std::vector<Superclass*> combatants;
    combatants.push_back(combatant1);
    combatants.push_back(combatant2);

    BattleDoer battleDoer;
    battleDoer.doBattle(combatants);

    delete combatant1;
    delete combatant2;
}
```

It is important to use pointers here. Only pointers and references can be used to provide polymorphism. You cannot have variables of type `Superclass` because it cannot be instantiated, you can only have references and pointers of type `Superclass`. Smart pointers should probably be used but I thought I'd keep it simple.

Comment: If the vector is defined in main, and the void doBattle function is defined in a battle class, how do i code the call in main so i can pass the vector

Comment: I've edited my answer, hopefully it helps.

Comment: Just a small nit: you have a memory leak. When a vector falls out of scope it calls the destructor of each object of the contained `Type`. Calling `~Type` when `Type` is a `Type*` is a non-op. You must manually `delete` each object first.

Comment: Thanks @Casey, I've added the deletes. I usually use smart pointers so I'm not used to manual deletion.